# How to add doubleclick event to Canvas element using the "AddEventListener" method?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events

I'm just trying to add a double click event to a HTML5 Canvas element. It works fine with:

```
myCanvas.ondbclick
```

However, I want to use the addEventListener method to do that. I guess it might be a simple task but I googled everywhere and could not find it. What's the name of the event I should be using?

```
myCanvas.addEventListener('doubleclick?', function(){ 

  // Some dazzling stuff happens be here

});
```

Hope it's possible, don't wanted to "break" my coding consistency.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The event name is `dblclick`:

```
myCanvas.addEventListener('dblclick', function(){ 

  // Some dazzling stuff happens be here

});
```

Also your first example is wrong, it should say:

```
myCanvas.ondblclick
```

Comment: Thanks. Its seems I need a better javascript cheat sheet.

Comment: the mdc docs are insanely useful for js development: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript

Comment: I am  using fabric js.
Which event is used for double click on canvas?